# Is it a good practice to add extra field to database model to speed up database queries?

Tags: django, database, database-design, django-models, django-views

I have Django project with two database models: Device and DeviceTest.

Every device in system should walk through some test stages from manufacturing to sale. And therefore many DeviceTest objects are connected to Device object through foreign key relationship:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class DeviceTest(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tester = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

In my project there 2 kind of pages:

1) page with all tests for individual device

2) page with all devices with their latest status and action

Now I'm trying to optimize 2) page. To get latest test data I use this code:

```
status_list = []
last_update_list = []
last_action_list = []

for dev in device_list:
    try:
        latest_test = DeviceTest.objects.filter(device_id=dev.pk).latest('created_at')
        status_list.append(latest_test.status)
        last_update_list.append(latest_test.created_at)
        last_action_list.append(latest_test.action)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        status_list.append("Not checked")
        last_update_list.append("Not checked")
        last_action_list.append("Not checked")
```

For now in my database ~600 devices and ~4000 tests. And this is the main bottleneck in page loading.

What are the ways to speed up this calculation?

I came up with idea of adding extra field to Device model: foreign key to its last DeviceTest. In this scenario there wouldn't be any complicated requests to database at all.

And now I have a few questions:

- Is it a good practice to add redundant field to model?
- Is it possible to write migration rule to fill this redundant field to all current Devices?
- And the most important, what are other choices to speed up my calculations?

Answer (score 1):

```
id_list = [dev.id for dev in device_list]
devtests = DeviceTest.objects.filter(
    device_id__in=id_list).order_by('-created_at').distinct('device')
```

That should give you, in one database call, in `devtests` only the latest entries for each `device_id` by `create_at` value.

Then do your loop and take the values from the list, instead of calling the database on each iteration.

However, it could also be a good idea to denormalize the database, like you suggested. Using "redundant fields" *can* definitely be good practice. You can automate the denormalization in the `save()` method or by listening to a `post_save()` signal from the related model.

**Edit**

*First a correction: should be `.distinct('device')` (not created_at)*

A list comprehension to fetch only the `id` values from the device_list. Equivalent to `Device.objects.filter(...).values_list('id', flat=True)`

```
id_list = [dev.id for dev in device_list]
```

Using the list of `id`s, we fetch all related `DeviceTest` objects

```
devtests = DeviceTest.objects.filter(device_id__in=id_list)
```

and order them by `created_at` but with the newest first `-created_at`. That also means, for every `Device`, the newest related `DeviceTest` will be first.

```
.order_by('-created_at')
```

Finally, for every `device` we only select the first related value we find (that would be the newest, because we sorted the values that way).

```
.distinct('device')
```

---

Additionally, you could also combine the device `id` and `DeviceTest` lookups

```
devtests = DeviceTest.objects.filter(device_in=Device.objects.filter(...))
```

then Django would create the SQL for it to do the `JOIN` in the database, so you don't need to load and loop the `id` list in Python.

Comment: Wouldn't  it be better to use the ``dev.id`` in the distinct clause? I'm proposing this because he'd get the latest``DeviceTest`` object by doing so.

Comment: I guess it would be the same. When the `id` is higher, the creation time will be later, too. Assuming `created_at` is the time that the object was first created. But it may be faster to use `id`, especially if `created_at` isn't indexed.

Comment: @C14L this gives me "DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend" error. According to Django docs arguments for distinct are allowed only in PostrgeSQL, and I have "'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'" in my settings.

Comment: @C14L Also, can you explain to me this query. I can't understand how this might work. After "filter" we will get DeviceTests objects that related only to devs in device_list, but completely not in order by Device or creation time? And after "order_by" we will sort it by time (not by individual Device test times, but common time)?? And after that we'll remove duplicates that have the same "creation_at" time?? It seems like this is not what we want at all, where am I wrong?

Comment: You are correct, it should of course be .distinct('device'), corrected my answer and added a step by step explanation.

Comment: @C14L Thanks! Now I fully understand it! But unfortunately, as I said earlier, I don't use PostgreSQL and ".distinct('device')" gives me error